# Pipe to bc gives inconsistent syntax errors

Tags: bash, pipe, bc

I have to pipe integers comparisons (and more complex arithmetic and boolean operations) to bc, and I have to keep track of syntax errors when some data is missing.

It seems I found some inconsistent behaviour with bc.

Of course :

`echo "1==7" | bc` gives boolean `0`

`echo "==7" | bc` gives `(standard_in) 1: syntax error`

But :

```
echo -e "==1\n==7" | bc
(standard_in) 1: syntax error`
7
```

instead of `7`, one would expect `(standard_in) 2: syntax error` on the second line.

For the sake of these explanations, I simplified the input of `bc` but I have to resolve this strange behaviour with much more complex arithmetic and boolean operations.

WORKAROUND
As @KamilCok noticed below, a workaround consists in inserting newlines

`echo -e "==1\n==7" | awk 'ORS="\n\n"' | bc`

Comment: I smell a bug. You should write to `bc` developers. Fun fact: try `==1\n========================7`. My guess the yacc parser is confused.

Comment: @KamilCuk For me, this gives same output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is a bug in yacc parser within GNU bc. I see that inserting a valid statement between comparisons seems to reset the state.

```
echo -e "==1\n1\n==7" | bc
(standard_in) 1: syntax error
1
(standard_in) 3: syntax error
```

So a workaround would be to input an empty valid statement (like just `1`) between comparisons. A real solution would be to write a patch to GNU `bc` and notify the developers.

Comment: Thanx. `echo -e "==1\n==7" | awk 'ORS="\n\n"' | bc` is a workaround. Don't know how to write a patch, but I notify the developpers.

Answer (score 1):

No this is absolutely consistent with keyboard input.

I suspect that `bc` has a *strange* parsing error behavior that's all.